# How do I change an href on first click and go to it on the second click?

Tags: jquery, onclick, href

I'm trying to change the text and href of a list item on the first click.  On the second click it should go to the new url.  These are a few ways I've tried:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="#">Click me</a></li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

This way changes text and then immediately goes to the new url.

```
$('ul.nav li:nth-child(1) a[href="#"]').click(function() {
  $(this).text('New Text');
  $(this).attr('href', 'http://www.website.com');
});
```

The second way switches text and href but preventDefault() is still keeping me from going to the new URL despite specifying a[href="#"] in the selector.

```
$('ul.nav li:nth-child(1) a[href="#"]').click(function(e) {
  $(this).text('New Text');
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).attr('href', 'http://www.website.com');
});
```

Comment: Check the `.one()` method [here](http://api.jquery.com/one/).

Comment: Your statement 'preventDefault() is still keeping me from going to the new URL despite specifying a[href="#"] in the selector' is not clear. Please elaborate it...

Comment: That's what `e.preventDefault()` is supposed to do, prevent the default behavior -- as inhan suggested, lookup `.one()`

Comment: Sorry I just started learning jQuery.  I thought that specifying a[href="INSERTURL"] was supposed to only select an href with that specific url.  My logic was that once clicking it once the url would change and wouldn't match what was in the selector anymore thus not firing a second time.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: @Jeff - If you use `.click()` or the non-delegated form of `.on()` it binds handlers to all of the elements that matched your selector at the time, and those handlers stay even if the elements are later updated such that they don't match any more. If you use the delegated form of `.on()` it will work as you imagined: `$('ul.nav li:nth-child(1)').on('click', 'a[href="#"]', function() {...`

Comment: Thanks for the clarity nnnnnn.  I'm really interested in learning more about jQuery in general and that bit of information will definitely come in handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use .one('click') instead to bind the click only once

```
$('ul.nav li:nth-child(1) a[href="#"]').one('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).text('New Text').attr('href', 'http://www.website.com');
});
```

Comment: +1. For some reason I didn't even think of `.one()` when writing my answer. Nice.

Comment: @nnnnnn haha, its cool, you got enough reputation points! time to share ;)

Comment: Awesome!  That's just what I was looking for.  I can't believe it was that easy.

Comment: @Jeff Yeah, sometimes we're so wrapped up we forget that somethings actually have a simple solution!... happy this works for you!

Answer (score 0):

You have several options, including removing the click handler after the first click (with non-delegated event handlers like you're using that will only affect the element just clicked):

```
$('ul.nav li:nth-child(1) a[href="#"]').click(function(e) {
  $(this).text('New Text')
         .attr('href', 'http://www.website.com')
         .off('click'); // remove click handler
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

...or setting a flag so you can tell if it's already been changed:

```
$('ul.nav li:nth-child(1) a[href="#"]').click(function(e) {
   var $this = $(this);
   if (!$this.data("urlChanged")) {
      $this.text('New Text')
           .attr('href', 'http://www.website.com')
           .data("urlChanged", true);
      e.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul.nav li:nth-child(1) a[href="#"]').click(function(e) {
  var elem = $(this);
  if(!elem.hasClass("changed")){
    elem.addClass("changed");
    $(this).text('New Text');
    $(this).attr('href', 'http://www.website.com');
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```